# Upper camel case to lower camel case as VS Code snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to create the following line as a snippet for VS Code:

```golang
MyFooVariable mytype `json:"myFooVariable"`
```

So I have the following snippet base

```
"Struct member declaration with json decorator": {
    "prefix": "json",
    "body": [
        "${1} ${2} `json:\"${1}\"`"
    ],
    "description": "Add suffix for json Marshaller"
}
```

On the second usage of `${1}` I want to replace the upper camel case by lower camel case. I guess I should use regex to make a substitution but as soon as I'm trying to do anything with regex my brain just runs away.

Could you help me with that?

I know I should show you what I attempted but believe me, it's irrelevant.

Comment: Try `${1/^(.)/${1:/downcase}/}`. And it is still relevant to see what you tried and how it worked.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Can you answer the question so I validate it, while explaining why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to turn the first character of the input word to lower case. So, you may use a simple `^(.)` regex to find that first char and capture it into Group 1 and then use `${1:/downcase}` to replace with a lowercase version of that character:

```
"body": [
    "${1} ${2} `json:\"${1/^(.)/${1:/downcase}/}\"`"
],
```

This is a ["rough" demo](https://regex101.com/r/lscPE8/1) of how it works.